# Select from a result from outer select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

Can someone help me if there is a shortcut to my scenario.

```
SELECT ProductName FROM Product where ProductId = 1012
```

the result of this statement is "DoubleDutch"

```
SELECT ColumnName FROM ProductMapping
```

The result of this statment is "ProductName"

```
SELECT (SELECT PM.ColumName FROM Product where ProductId = 1012) FROM ProductMapping PM
```

Now i was just expecting that the result would be "DoubleDutch" 
but the result is still "ProductName"

Comment: I think you should check your question again. It is confusing little bit. and also tell us which are the columns in TableA and TableB

Comment: At the moment it's unclear what you asking. Please provide sample input like - here's data in TableA, here's data in TableB and sample output like - I want to get recordset like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(1000), @sql NVARCHAR(max)
SELECT @Col = ValueFromTableB from TableA
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + @Col + ' FROM TableB
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: the idea is right but i think there should be change  .. instead of `SELECT @Col = ValueFromTableB from TableA` it should be `SELECT @Col = ValueFromTableB from TableB ` and instead of `SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + @Col + ' FROM TableB` it should be `SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + @Col + ' FROM TableA`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you

```
DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(1000), @sql NVARCHAR(max)
Set @Col  = ''
SELECT @Col = @Col + ValueFromTableB + ' , ' from TableB
Set @Col = Left(@Col , (LEN(@Col) - 1))
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT TableAId , ' + @Col + ' FROM TableA'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```